# Moss scheduling Simulator and Standard Deviation in plain english?

Tags: standard-deviation, simulation

source : http://www.ontko.com/moss/sched/user_guide.html

***Configuration File Options standdev***

n

*

> The number of standard deviations from the average length of time a
>   process should execute before terminating.

*

Can any one telling me what the above line means in simple English please? or show by some calculations.

I was not able to find a better forum to ask this question, so please suggest if there is a better stackexchange. thanks

yes i know what is standard deviation, but the line "Number of sd a process should execute is confusing"

help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it says "meandev: The average length of time in milliseconds that a process should execute before terminating" and "standdev: The number of standard deviations from the average length of time a process should execute before terminating" my guess is that it means that the pair of parameters (meandev, standdev) together specify the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution, and MOSS then creates programs that run for lengths of time drawn from this distribution.